# Не получается остановить виртуальную среду в Python (VS code)

Tags: python, venv

Всем привет, недавно начала изучать виртуальные среды в питоне. Нужно создать новую папку .venv и там инсталлировать Django определенной версии.
На мою команду в терминале:

```
PS C:\Users\marin\Python\courses> pipenv install django==4.0.8
```

получаю ответ:

```
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically
 use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. 
You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment 
and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Installing django==4.0.8...
Resolving django==4.0.8...
Installation Succeeded
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (11356d)...                                              
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

Новая виртуальная среда не создается, путь новой виртуальной среды не создался.

Ищу местоположение виртуальной среды:

```
PS C:\Users\marin\Python\courses> pipenv --venv
```

получаю:

```
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, 
so it will automatically use that environment, 
instead of creating its own for any project. 
You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment
 and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
C:\Users\marin\.virtualenvs\Python-MrqR-F-V
```

и вот я нахожу путь к действующей виртуальной среде, но как бы я не пыталась ее остановить, ничего не получается, ни через exit ни через deactivate.
Буду очень признательна за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

- Открой командную строку
- Создай папку проекта `mkdir new_project`
- Перейди в папку проекта `cd new_project`
- Создай виртуальное окружение `python -m venv venv`
- Перейди в папку Scripts `cd venv/Scripts`
- Активируй виртуальное окружение `activate`

**Итог:** (venv) D:\new_project\venv\Scripts>

- перейди в папку проекта `cd ..` `cd ..`
- установи Django `pip install django`
- создай проект `django-admin startproject mysite`